# Where does UX fit into captology, if at all?

Tags: user-behavior, research

I only recently came across the field of research known as captology, where the psychological principles of persuasion is combined with computer technology. Assuming that user experience design already involves a significant amount of study in psychology and user behaviour, how much more does this field really add to UX in general, and has the been any specific projects that you have worked on where you have taken these concepts into consideration?

Some links on this topic if you are interested:
http://captology.stanford.edu/
http://www.persuasionapi.com/

Comment: BJ Fogg and his group focuses on behavior design. Their practices are quite well within the scope of UX and he organizes regular workshops to teach UX folks about Behavior design. I have worked on a couple healthcare projects where we have used some of his work - The Fogg model.

Comment: Is this generally applied to the information architecture, user interface design, interaction design or all three? I will have to look into this in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

I used it for my master thesis together with Design with Intent (DwI) cards. In addition to this, I used it for consuming more fruit behavior. Changing behavior needs an intent and a replacement to the existing one in general.

Persuasive Design is not only about digitization of the services but instead a variable in social, contextual,product service domain. There are some sub-strategies like assisting, suggestive and to be honest, it is very open...

You can check this set of cards which will make you to understand the intent: http://www.danlockton.com/dwi/Main_Page

It may lead you to figure out another world that design can change for a purpose.

Another example is my friends master thesis, insights by Wouter Middendorf, he created also a set of card for persuasive strategies for common usage. Here is another link: http://www.middendorf.nl/insights/

Persuasive is not a new thing, it generally diffuses our choices but designing for that was something new in early 2000's.

Common examples:

- Scarcity (there is limited place in plane)
- Suggestive (people who bought this, bought also this)
- Assisting (you completed the first week training schedule, let me arrange the second week for you)

Before believing such messages, there should be trust between two parties. Trust is for white strategies, while it is not needed when you are using black strategies of persuasion.

Answer (score 1):

There's Human Factors International methodology of persuasive design called PET design™, which stands for Persuasion, Emotion and Trust, rooted in
social psychology, and based on Fogg, Caldini, Weinschenk and other researchers. As HFI certified user experience analyst I've used this methodology in practice. Please, check some links on this topic:

- [Chris Lock - Persuasion, Emotion and Trust in Online Banking](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XO0fwI0FmHQ)
- [Persuasion, Emotion, and Trust (PET) design in action](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-JjHtke2Yew)
- [Beyond Usability: Designing Web Sites for Persuasion, Emotion, and Trust](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2009/01/beyond-usability-designing-web-sites-for-persuasion-emotion-and-trust.php)
- [UX Brighton: Rob Gillham - Designing for Persuasion, Emotion and Trust On The Web](http://vimeo.com/6096980)